# how to implement notification in android TV

Tags: android-notifications, android-tv

Can it possible to send push notification in Android TV through FCM? 
If it is possible then how can we send push notification through FCM and how to show it in Android TV?

Comment: Did you achieve it? I am also interested to know it.

Comment: @anoop4real I did not achieve it right now

Comment: I tried a sample and it works with FCM push....for me I don’t have a requirement to show it on the tv, I just wanted to make sure that it will receive the payload and it does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send notifications to Android TV, they will arrive to your service.
Now that since there is no system tray, there is no default UI got them, so you need to do that yourself, you can't use the default behavior and you can't use notification manager.

Answer (score -1):

I think notification will appear just as recommendations and not as "notification".
One option will be using [toasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView) or even a [notification-android-tv](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.cyberdream.androidtv.notifications.google)

Comment: No you can't. What you can do is in background check one API to get new information to show at the recommendations. I am not 100% sure that is the best way to do, but at least is an idea.