# Opening Android Notifications programmatically

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-tv

Is there any possibility to open Notifications Menu in my app? I'm looking for solution similar to one below that opens System Settings side bar:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Comment: So, you want to open notification's setting?

Comment: No, I want to open notifications side bar that displays unread, system and other apps, notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution, looks like sample below does the work. However I couldn't find any documentation about *com.android.tv.NOTIFICATIONS_PANEL* action.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("com.android.tv.NOTIFICATIONS_PANEL");
startActivity(notificationIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to try using [toasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView) or [notification-android-tv](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.cyberdream.androidtv.notifications.google).

Also, do take note that:

> notification will appear just as recommendations and not as
>   "notification"

For further info, you can refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279488/how-to-implement-notification-in-android-tv).